# How do I create a model dynamically with introspection in django?

Tags: django, django-models, introspection

Hi want to create a database model using introspection.
When I run `introspection.get_table_description(cursor, 'someModeLName')`
the `TableDoesNotExist(table)` error is raised. Is this how to create a model or I got it completely wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/introspection.py", line 81, in get_table_description
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM %s LIMIT 1" % self.connection.ops.quote_name(table_name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "shapefile_1" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM "shapefile_1" LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Have you run `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: @Sid Yes i've done all that but i am still get the error

Answer (score 0):

you can find here:

[django/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py)